# Get the same output of the nproc command in Python

Tags: python, docker, multiprocessing, cgroups

When using cgroups to limit the number of available CPUs, such as using the `--cpuset-cpus` flag in Docker, the `nproc` command prints the number of available CPUs while taking that limit into account. Python's `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` prints the number of CPUs in the host regardless the cgroup limitation. Which function of Python should be called on order to get the same number returned by `nproc`? I wish to avoid running the `nproc` binary using Python.

Comment: Counting via CPU affinity is messy, full of glibc specific-version ifdefs and host system ifdefs and so on. You really will be better off just running `nproc` directly...